# Updateing to Vue 2.6 and PrimeVue 2.4 - Cannot read property 'ripple' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, ripple, primevue

After updateing primevue to 2.4.x, using Serenity template, I got like 200+ console errors on dashboard:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in directive ripple inserted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ripple' of undefined"    
found in    
---> <AppSubmenu> at src/AppSubmenu.vue
       <AppMenu> at src/AppMenu.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <AppContainer> at src/AppContainer.vue
             <Root>
```

Of course, if I remove the directive from the AppSubmenu, the problem will occus at Button, DataTables, Panels, etc.

The other error I got so many times:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ripple' of undefined
    at inserted (Ripple.js?15f1:79)
    at callHook$1 (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6680)
    at callInsert (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6619)
    at wrappedHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2235)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at Object.invoker [as insert] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2175)
    at invokeInsertHook (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6346)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6565)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3948)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066)
```

How can I get rid of it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To fix the ripple effect issue, you need to declare the ripple directive. Here's how you can do it:

In your VUE main.js file:

```
import Ripple from 'primevue/ripple';

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)
app.directive('ripple', Ripple);
```